# IPv6 in a Windows XP/Windows 2003 Network

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, ipv6

Has anyone successfully deployed an IPv6 network in an environment with Windows XP SP3 workstations and Windows 2003 R2 servers?  Are there any operating system issues one needs to consider?  Does the windows firewall still work under Windows XP?

Comment: The first question is highly subjective. Some will say "yes", others will say "no"... and what would be the right answer?

Comment: I am just looking to get some feedback from people who have gone through the process.  What issues have they run into?  Anything to keep in mind during the switch?  I was looking for more than a 'yes'/'no' answer. I apologize if that was not clear.

Comment: @Juliano: 42 would be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Despite Juliano's observation, I answer the first question with "yes": I have done so. In XP and W2k3R2, there are certainly still IPv6 issues. For example, the DNS server support is limited (it supports the records, but not in the "nice" way in which W2k8 does it). The biggest problem is that RDP still doesn't use IPv6, so Linux RDP clients often fail to connect (especially over SSH tunnels). The firewall works fine, AFAIK.