# Windows Server 2003 RDP not listening on IPv6

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, ipv6, terminal-server

i have a Windows Server 2003 machine; with IPv6 enabled:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : newland.local
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.244
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:████:████:███:████:████:████
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:1dff:fe86:fdf2%4
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                       fe80::250:bfff:fe91:955f%4
```

i *can* connect to IIS server using IPv, remotely and locally, using IPv4 and IPv6:

```
> telnet 127.0.0.1 80                       (connects)
> telnet 192.168.1.244 80                   (connects)
> telnet ::1 80                             (connects)
> telnet fe80::224:1dff:fe86:fdf2 80        (connects)
```

And TCPView shows that the server is listening on port 80:

[image]

> **Note**: This is useful to establish that Windows Server 2003 *does* have support for IPv6 services.

And i *can* connect to terminal services, locally and remotely, using IPv4:

```
> telnet 127.0.0.1 3389                     (connects)
> telnet 192.168.1.244 3389                 (connects)
```

But i **cannot** connect to RDP, locally or remotely, over IPv6:

```
> telnet ::1 3389                           (fails to connect)
> telnet fe80::224:1dff:fe86:fdf2 3389      (fails to connect)
```

We can see that the system is listening on 3389:

[image]

Except [why won't it listen](http://assets.diylol.com/hfs/356/2e6/675/resized/y-u-no-meme-generator-people-y-u-no-listen-2a0fb4.jpg) on port 3389 (ipv6)?

---

Unfortunately it's not the firewall. Aside from the fact that i'm connecting locally (in which case the firewall doesn't apply), the firewall doesn't apply:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP is limited to listening on 0.0.0.0, which is IPv4. Windows 2003's network stack is based on the Windows XP stack. That stack has IPv6 added as an afterthought and it shows. Windows 2008 has a 'real' IPv6 stack and will offer much better support.

Answer (score 1):

This command will do the trick.
netsh interface portproxy add v6tov4 listenport=3389 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=3389

After using it you'll be able to connect using a recent version of Remote Desktop Client over IPv6 to a WinXP/Win2k3 box.

Regards
Viswanathan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a Windows 2003 limitation addressed in 2008.

https://serverfault.com/a/196639/35088